# Get ResultSet value in textfield

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

I am trying to output the value "name" (which is stored in the database), in the txtfield (txtfldName). But when I execute the program and click on the button nothing happens. That is the part of the code:

```
btnStudent.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  try {
          String newquery = "SELECT * FROM test";
          ps= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(newquery);
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

          if(rs.next()){
               txtfldName= rs.getString("name");
          }
```

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Nothing happens? No error? You need to learn how to debug to know what source code line causing the error.

Comment: no nothing. That's the reason why I'm confused. When I click on the button noting happens. @Loc

Comment: Does your sql work if run stand-alone? Where are you populating 'con'? You really should be checking for errors on each database request (if it can go wrong, it will go wrong, especially while it's still under development) - that way you can see properly where it's failing.

Comment: Also, I would make the code output /something/ (to be removed once all is well), so that you can be sure it's being executed at all.

Comment: @MandyShaw. I debug the code and I get an error at `txtfldName= rs.getString("name");` Edit source code.. don't know what that means

Comment: What's the specific error message?

Comment: always get this null Pointer message source not found